# Excel Interop COMException HRESULT: 0x800A03EC when accessing hidden cell

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

I'm having issues accessing a named cell in Excel from C# using Excel Interop when the cell is hidden and I access it like so:

```
bool SomeBoolean = WorkSheet.Range["MyRangeName"].Value;
```

The Range property implicitly calls `get_range` when I'm accessing it, which is what's throwing the exception according to the stack trace. The code used to call `get_range` directly, and that had similar results.

If I unhide the cells, it works fine. If I step through the code line by line, it works fine (this is always a frustrating situation).

Of course I can solve this by unhiding the cells, but I'd like to try to find a more elegant solution. I've pored over the MSDN documentation and several threads here on SO, but I can't seem to find anything. Any help would be much appreciated!

MSDN page for Worksheet.Range: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836512.aspx

Comment: I cannot repeat this problem.  I know I've accessed hidden ranges in the past -- Interop (or VBA for that matter) never seem to care.  Quite the contrary, I have to go out of my way to avoid hidden ranges.  I ran this as a test, and I seriously cannot get it to throw that error.  Can you upload your spreadsheet (or the relevant portion of it) to DropBox or something similar?  I'm extremely curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for trying to help me solve this mystery. During my debugging, I noticed that sometimes it worked, mysteriously, and other times not, and I went over the code leading up to the line in question.

The cause of this issue was that the Range is being searched from a worksheet which is set as the currently-selected worksheet at the time the plugin is called. So if the correct tab in the workbook isn't selected at call time, it fails. If it is selected, it succeeds. As it turns out it's nothing to do with the cells being hidden. Rather frustrating, but at least now we know!

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. By definition, hidden cells are not accessible.

Try it yourself. Create a worksheet in Excel, hide some columns, and then search (By Values, not Formulas) for a value in a hidden cell. You will get a dialog box indicating that the value could not be found.

If you don't agree with this behavior, then take it up with Microsoft.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, Dan. I tried what you suggested and saw the same message you did. The code I'm working with is a .Net rewrite of an old VBA plugin we inherited (an XLAM file). The tricky thing is that this VBA plugin has no issues accessing the hidden cell values, which is confusing to me. It makes sense that if it's never accessible, and that's by design, that I shouldn't be able to access it with C#. But why does VBA work, then? I'm not very experienced with Excel programming so perhaps I'm missing something here...

Comment: Hmm, without debugging it or inspecting the interop assembly I'm not sure. If it was my app, I would simply unhide the cells before getting their value. Working with Office interops is rarely elegant. The other solution might be to use a third-party library like EPPlus, but I'm not sure what your macro does.